# Illustrator: making a compound path permanent?

Tags: shapes

I have two shapes overlapping each other as a compound path so that the top shape is a cut out of the bottom shape. Is there a way to make this compound path relationship permanent so that it can't be undone?

Comment: A diagram is definitely going to be helpful here.

Comment: If you drew a circle and then a smaller circle on top of the first circle and combined them as a compound path, you would have a donut. Is there any way to make this donut permanent so that somebody couldn't release the compound path and have just two overlapping circles?

Comment: To my knowledge the only way to prevent someone releasing the compound path is to lock the layer. You cannot expand the compound path.

Comment: Hold option when you click on the pathfinder icon to create the compound path. That will enable the expand option next to the icons. Click expand and you now have a new shape from the compound path.

Comment: @The_Machine This is not possible. Compound paths can always be released if they are in an editable file format (AI, EPS, among others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. A compound path is the only mechanism which allows you to make holes in paths. So want a hole then it is a compound path. Period.

In genral it is not possible to lock users out of the data even if this was possible. So undoing it would be no harder than asking the program to rebuild the shape.

This said it is possible to make a path that appears having a hole while it does not. I can still sidestep this though.